# Can't get updated values in array after using .map method

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I need to implement a method, which works that way:

```
# do_magic("abcd") # "Aaaa-Bbb-Cc-D"
# do_magic("a")    # "A"
# do_magic("ab")   # "Aa-B"
# do_magic("teSt") # "Tttt-Eee-Ss-T"
```

My decision was to convert a string into an array, iterate through this array and save the result. The code works properly inside the block, but I'm unable to get the array with updated values with this solution, it returns the same string divided by a dash (for example "t-e-S-t" when ".map" used or "3-2-1-0" when ".map!" used):

```
def do_magic(str)
  letters = str.split ''
  counter = letters.length
  while counter > 0
    letters.map! do |letter|
      (letter * counter).capitalize
      counter -= 1
    end
  end
  puts letters.join('-')
end
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: The while-loop is pointless and misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close. When you have a block (`letters.map!`), the return of that block is the last evaluated statement. In this case, `counter -= 1` is being mapped into `letters`.

Try

```
l = (letter * counter).capitalize
counter -= 1
l
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly -  do_magic("sdfsdf") returns "5-4-3-2-1-0"

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this using `each_with_index`

```
def do_magic(str)
    letters = str.split("")
    length = letters.length
    new_letters = []
    letters.each_with_index do |letter, i|
        new_letters << (letter * (length - i)).capitalize
    end
    new_letters.join("-")
end
```

OR

using `map_with_index` equivalent `each_with_index.map`

```
def do_magic(str)
    letters = str.split("")
    length = letters.length
    letters.each_with_index.map { |letter, i| 
       (letter * (length - i)).capitalize 
    }.join("-")
end
```

Comment: You can use `chars` instead of `split("")`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following.

```
def do_magic(letters)
  length = letters.size
  letters.downcase.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) { |(letter, i), new_letters|
    new_letters << (letter * (length - i)).capitalize }.join
end

do_magic 'teSt'
  # => "TtttEeeSsT"
```

Let's go through the steps.

```
letters = 'teSt'

length = letters.size
  #=> 4
str = letters.downcase
  #=> "test"
enum0 = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "test":each_char>
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "test":each_char>:with_index>
enum2 = enum1.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "test":each_char>:
  #     with_index>:with_object([])>
```

Carefully examine the return values from the creation of the enumerators `enum0`, `enum1` and `enum2`. The latter two may be thought of as *compound enumerators*.

The first element is generated by `enum2` (the value of `enum2.next`) and the block variables are assigned values using *disambiguation* (aka *decomposition*).

```
(letter, i), new_letters = enum2.next
  #=> [["t", 0], []]
letter
  #=> "t"
i #=> 0
new_letters
  #=> []
```

The block calculation is then performed.

```
m = letter * (length - i)
  #=> "tttt"
n = m.capitalize
  #=> "Tttt"
new_letters << n
  #=> ["Tttt"]
```

The next element is generated by `enum2`, passed to the block and the block calculations are performed.

```
(letter, i), new_letters = enum2.next
  #=> [["e", 1], ["Tttt"]]
letter
  #=> "e"
i #=> 1
new_letters
  #=> ["Tttt"]
```

Notice how `new_letters` has been updated. The block calculation is as follows.

```
m = letter * (length - i)
  #=> "eee"
n = m.capitalize
  #=> "Eee"
new_letters << n
  #=> ["Tttt", "Eee"]
```

After the last two elements of `enum2` are generated we have

```
new_letters
  #=> ["Tttt", "Eee", "Se", "T"]
```

The last step is to combine the elements of `new_letters` to form a single string.

```
new_letters.join
  #=> "TtttEeeSeT"
```